# Software to detect grammar constructions in a sentence

Tags: nlp, linguistics

I have the following sentence:
`She usually walks three miles a day`. There are several grammar elements here, like `present simple`, `personal pronouns`, `numerals`, etc. Is there a software that can detect these?

Comment: This would be better suited to cross-validated and ask for algorithms rather than software... Then you can search for implementations of a particular algorithm.

Comment: Simple grammatical analysis is typically performed by POS taggers. You can get fairly detailed subcategorization (not just *verb* but tagged for number, tense, etc) with most systems. For languages with real inflection systems, you probably want a morphological analyzer instead, or as well.

Comment: @hally9k Why cross-validated? This isn't statistics.

Comment: @tripleee You are more than likely correct, where would you place this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to find an English [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). There are many different techniques and tools for parsing. [NLTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit) includes extensive capabilities for parsing ([here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/parse.html)). If you want something easy and ready-made, you can use the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) which is also available as a Java program. Your example sentence is parsed as the following:

```
She/PRP usually/RB walks/VBZ three/CD miles/NNS a/DT day/NN

(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP She))
    (VP
      (ADVP (RB usually))
      (VBZ walks)
      (NP
        (NP (CD three) (NNS miles))
        (NP (DT a) (NN day))))))

   Universal dependencies

        nsubj(walks-3, She-1)
        advmod(walks-3, usually-2)
        root(ROOT-0, walks-3)
        nummod(miles-5, three-4)
        dobj(walks-3, miles-5)
        det(day-7, a-6)
        dep(miles-5, day-7)

   Universal dependencies, enhanced

        nsubj(walks-3, She-1)
        advmod(walks-3, usually-2)
        root(ROOT-0, walks-3)
        nummod(miles-5, three-4)
        dobj(walks-3, miles-5)
        det(day-7, a-6)
        dep(miles-5, day-7)
```

This may look rather cryptic but actually it does contain all the information you are looking for. For example in `walks/VBZ`, `VBZ` means `Verb, 3rd person singular present`. `PRP` means `Personal Pronoun` or `CD` means `Cardinal Number`. These are abbreviations used in the [Penn Treebank](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/). You can find most of these [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.9.8216&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The last part deals with dependencies. For instance `advmod(walks-3, usually-2)` means the adverb `usually` refers to the verb `walks` etc.